# Which powers/skills does Noumu have?

Tags: my-hero-academia

It's mentioned and shown in the anime that Noumu has shock absorption, regeneration and it's as strong as All Might. Are those all the powers it has? Or does it have other powers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There hasn't been any other demonstration of their powers other than what was shown the USJ fight, which includes what you've mentioned above, so we can't assume that they have anything else. We know that they're artificial beings that have been experimented on to have multiple quirks, so we may end up seeing other powers at some other point.

> As of the recent chapter, 143, though this has not been expanded upon

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are an anime-only viewer of the series. For that "noumu" yes those quirks that were demonstrated can be interpreted as the only quirks it posses. You will see later down the line if you follow the series in the upcoming season a deeper explanation of what/who Noumu is and who/what Noumu/s were before as well as any quirks they may have and how they derived them. However, if you can't wait for the next season feel free to read the manga and you will come to understand it much faster than the anime.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. It's better to include any info that answers the question directly even if it could spoil the asker. You can always [edit] your post, also to put a spoiler, start the paragraph with `>!`, e.g. `>! this is a spoiler`. Note that the Q&A here should be useful to anyone, not only the asker. To understand more how this site works, consider taking a quick [tour].